# Acronym generates abnormal spacing

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, acronyms

I'm using the acronym package but I just realized that it has some problem with spacing. It is the last version (2012).
Every time an acronym starts a new line, at the end of the previous line there is a small white space, very annoying to me!

How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[artemisia]{textgreek}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[version-1-compatibility,group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Just after (less than \SI{5}{\minute}) exogenous stimuli on a preadipocyte, \ac{CREB} is phosphorylated and 
increase expression of \ac{CEBP}, in particular the two isoforms
\ac{CEBPb} and \ac{CEBPd}. This two transcription factors are inactive, this means that they are not able 
to bind DNA, and thus they accumulate in the cytosol. 
During the passage from G1 to S phase of cell cycle, \ac{CEBPb} is hyperphosphorylated and activated by
\ac{GSK3b} and \ac{MAPK}. Phosphorylation allow \ac{CEBPb} to homodimerize and to bind DNA, starting
mitotic clonal expansion of preadipocyte.
Subsequently \ac{CEBPb} and \ac{CEBPd} induce expression of \ac{CEBPa} and \ac{PPARg},
the two main transcription factor for adipocyte development.\ac{PPARg} dimerize with \ac{RXR}, thus being activated. 
Once both \ac{PPARg} and \ac{CEBPa} are activated they regulate each other, maintaining high expression 
levels and decreasing the ones of \ac{CEBPb} and \ac{CEBPd} (see \figurename{} 
\ref{img:cebps}).


\begin{acronym}[AAAAAA]
\acro{CEBP}[C/EBP]{CCAAT/enhancer binding protein}
\acro{CEBPa}[C/EBP\textalpha]{CCAAT/\-en\-hanc\-er binding protein alpha}
\acro{CEBPb}[C/EBP\textbeta]{CCAAT/\-en\-hanc\-er binding protein beta}
\acro{CEBPd}[C/EBP\textdelta]{CCAAT/\-en\-hanc\-er binding protein delta}
\acro{PPARg}[PPAR\textgamma]{peroxisome pro\-life\-rator-activated receptor gamma}
\acro{MSC}{mesenchimal stem cell}
\acro{RXR}{retinoid X receptor}
\acro{GSK3b}[GSK3\textbeta]{glycogen synthase kinase-3 beta}
\acro{MAPK}{mitogen-activated protein kinase}
\acro{CREB}{cyclic AMP response element-binding protein}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image: Problem with right margin]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Could you please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot post a picture of the result!

Comment: You might consider using the glossaries package instead. In my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120677/restore-headings-section I posted a minimal example.

Comment: @Stefano_g after I add `\end{acronym}` the example compiles but I don't see any unexpected spacing...

Comment: @Stefano_g You *can* post an image; just use the interface, clicking on the "inser image" button and remove the `!` that precedes the internal link. A user with enough privileges will reinstate it.

Comment: In my file there is the end. Just forgot here. Glossaries would be less comfortable. 
The problem is when I have a sentence and the long acronym is the first word on the new line on the previous I have a blank space. It is not justified to the other lines.

Comment: @Stefano_g Please, update with the full text of the example.

Comment: Done! trying on a online latex compiler I don't have that problem, but I have a totally different line breaking. Probabily due to a different column width.

Comment: I added a space in `adipocyte development. \ac{PPARg}` and no strange space appears any more. It shows again (elsewhere) when `microtype` is loaded. :(

Comment: the problem is in

    `induce expression of \ac{CEBPa}`
and

    `dimerize with \ac{RXR}`

Comment: This seems to be caused by the `\hskip\z@` after `\AC@placelabel{#1}` in the definition of `\@acf`. I don't know if it's safe to remove it, though...

Comment: I'm not expert enough but do you think it's possible to try a `\renewcommand`? If yes how?

Comment: @cgnieder It just inserts a line break point between `\AC@placelabel{#1}` and `\AC@acl{#1}`. Is it desirable?

Comment: after some judicious editing to force even more lines to begin with acronyms, and testing with two different versions of `acronym.sty` (v1.36 from tex live 2012, and v1.38 from ctan), the only "extra space" i found was when `CCAAT/enhancer` (from "binding protein delta") started a new line.  this is input as `CCAAT/\-en\-hanc\-er` to enable hyphenation, and as @cgnieder observes, appears to be caused by `\hskip\z@`; that, in turn, was added in the new version: "fix for non hyphenation of first word in long form" (see package CHANGES file).  report this to package author.

Comment: @Stefano_g the easiest way: load the `etoolbox` package and then add (between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` _twice_ `\patchcmd\@acf{\hskip\z@}{}{}{}`. This will remove both occurrences of `\hskip\z@` where in this case the second one is the important one.

Comment: Great!!! It works! Thanks a lot! @cgnieder you should answer it officially!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>from the comments:</sub>

It seems that `acronym` introduced `\hskip\z@` in the definition of `\@acf` as „fix for non hyphenation of first word in long form“ in v1.37. This seems to be the cause of the spurious space. Indeed, removing it by saying

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@acf{\hskip\z@}{}{}{}
\patchcmd\@acf{\hskip\z@}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

gives the correct output again. The `\hskip\z@` needs to be removed twice as the first one is used in the footnote version of the long form and only the second one in the default appearance:

```
% definition of \@acf in v1.38:
\newcommand*{\@acf}[1]{%
    \ifAC@footnote
       \acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}}%
       \footnote{\AC@placelabel{#1}\hskip\z@\AC@acl{#1}{}}%
    \else
       \acffont{%
          \AC@placelabel{#1}\hskip\z@\AC@acl{#1}%
          \nolinebreak[3] %
          \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@acs{#1}})}%
        }%
     \fi
     \ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi}
```

You might want to treat `\@acfp` the same way - it contains the same two instances of `\hskip\z@`.